# New bounty system question votes

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, bounties

If i open a bounty to a question asked by another user, some users may up/down vote the question.. Now my question to whom  the reputation be added/deducted myself or the question poster...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would the question votes affect you, as the bounty owner? You didn't *create* the question.

It is true that bounty questions will tend to get a bit more attention and (possibly) votes, but that's the intention, isn't it?